Mutating trigger when I update a table where I'm not reading data
I'm trying to copy data from one table (t_equipment) to another table (t_work_order) using a AFTER UPDATE trigger in Oracle.
However, I'm encountering a mutating trigger error, even though I'm not directly inserting or updating data in the same table from which I'm selecting.
Here's the trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TCI_AU_UPDATE_WORK_ORDER
AFTER UPDATE ON t_equipment
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    new_ereq_number5            NUMBER := :NEW.EREQ_NUMBER5;
    new_ereq_description_extra3 VARCHAR2(100) := :NEW.EREQ_DESCRIPTION_EXTRA3;
    new_ereq_choice1            VARCHAR2(50) := :NEW.EREQ_CHOICE1;
    new_ereq_description_extra4 VARCHAR2(100) := :NEW.EREQ_DESCRIPTION_EXTRA4;
    ereq_code                   VARCHAR2(100) := :NEW.EREQ_CODE;
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_work_order
    SET WOWO_NUMBER5 = new_ereq_number5,
        WOWO_DESCRIPTION_EXTRA1 = new_ereq_description_extra3,
        WOWO_CHOICE1 = new_ereq_choice1,
        WOWO_DESCRIPTION_EXTRA4 = new_ereq_description_extra4
    WHERE WOWO_EQUIPMENT = ereq_code;
END;
/


Is there something I'm missing, or is there a better way to handle this type of data copy between tables to avoid this issue?

A table mutates, not a trigger. Code you posted won't raise that error. Could you, please, edit the message and provide the whole example (including CREATE TABLE for both tables involved, as well as sample data you're working with and exact error you got)?

Not relevant to your problem (which I'd guess is coming from a trigger on the other table, but that's why we need to full error etc.), but why are you declaring local variables - why aren't you just using the :NEW values directly in the update statement?

Is it possible that the error is raised because another trigger on the same table is modyfing data on the table I'm trying to update?

@AlexPoole your question is pretty understandable. I needed that solution because the original trigger was different and had different purposes but the same problem

Your trigger updates t_work_order. And there probably is another triger on t_work_order in which you access the table t_equipment. Or maybe even more triggers are involved, say, a trigger on t_work_order updating table xyz and a trigger on xyz that accesses t_equipment.

The real problem seems to be your database. Why do you need that information in table t_work_order at all? Instead there should be a last update timestamp in table t_equipment, so you can always query the latest updated row for a wowo_equipment.

In addition to checking for a mutually-referencing trigger, also check if you have a foreign key on t_work_order pointing to a PK/UK on t_equipment.ereq_number5. But as for your question, "Is there a better way...?" Yes... don't do it at all. This is denormalizing your data which creates a bad design. Get the equipment detail while querying t_work_order by joining it to the t_equipment table at query time. Don't put non-key t_equipment fields in the actual t_work_order table.
